# AngularDart structural directive add custom content

Tags: angular-dart

Is there some chance to simple update _viewContainer??

I am trying create directive for material-button component, that add hidden classic button for submit form by hit enter key. I need to add simple html to _viewContainer, something like this

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Directive(
  selector: '[kpMaterialSubmit]',
)
class KpMaterialSubmit {
  final TemplateRef _templateRef;
  final ViewContainerRef _viewContainer;

  KpMaterialSubmit(this._viewContainer, this._templateRef);

  @Input()
  set kpMaterialSubmit(bool showButton) {
    _viewContainer.clear();
    if (showButton) {
      _viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(_templateRef);

      //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
      _viewContainer.createMyCustomView('<button class="hidden">Submit</button>');
    } else {
      _viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(_templateRef);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar and it works. I don't know if there is a better way.

Instead of using html text directly, create a component.

Add the import to the component template:

```
import 'package:<your package>/<path to component>/<component source name>.template.dart';
```

Then add the component with the createComponent() method (instead of createMyCustomView()):

```
_viewContainer.createComponent(<componentName>NgFactory);
```

That's all!

If you need to style the component or add any attribute you can get the reference and derive the HtmlElement instance:

```
ComponentRef _componentRef = _viewContainer.createComponent(<componentName>NgFactory);
HtmlElement element = _componentRef.location;
element.style.background = 'green';
element.setAttribute('value', 'text');
```